# Laravel, не проходит аутентификация

Tags: php, laravel

Всем привет. Сделал аутентификацию как на этом видео https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lc3MMZX4XIs&index=4&list=PLD5U-C5KK50UaCJFcN8Zh7MnSnj4MbrZP  (6 минут идет), при вводе email и пароля снова редиректит на поля ввода логина и пароля. В чем может быть проблема? Лару только начал изучать.

Comment: Проверьте название таблицы пользователей, и её название столбцов. Сверка должна идти по столбцам email и password

Comment: Я мигрировал таблицу из Laravel, так что ошибок в названиях быть не может, регистрация проходит, аутентификация нет.

Comment: Запустите с отладкой и пошагово пройдитесь по коду